# Why it is not recommend to use root login in linux

Tags: linux, networking, security, fedora

I am a developer using Linux fedora.I seen in lot of links that it is not a good idea to use root user,because someone can easily hack my password.Instead create a separate account for development purpose.But i am using my own fedora machine and myself only using.In this case is it recommend to use a separate account instead of "root".Need more clarification

Comment: If I were you, I'd use a non-root user. It's just good practice. I'm no developer, but I'd imagine you'd want to code as a non-root user as well, to ensure that your code works well when *not* logged in as a root user, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Using root in Linux is like using the default account in Windows XP... full system control with no restrictions... bad idea...

Answer (score 5):

The primary reasons are thus:

- Every hacker / virus knows that there is a root account. If they are blindly attacking a system, it's a known entry point, and very likely to be a target. This is why your root account should have logins disabled.
- Everyone makes mistakes. You'll be in a rush, accidentally hit the wrong key, not double-check/realize the full list of files in that wildcard you just entered... eventually, you'll be sitting at your system thinking. "Crap. I did not want to do that. How do I undo that?" It happens to the best of us. By not using the root account, you can be relatively confident that whatever you just did, did *not* mess up your system's ability to operate.
- Privilege escalation - If there is a security vulnerability that's exploited (in say, your web browser), by not running your programs as root will limit damage. If your web browser is running as root (because you logged in as root), then any security failures will have access to your entire system.
- Acountability - There is only one root account. If everything is using the root account, it's difficult to find out who did what. This applies less in a single-user environment, but that's still not a good argument to avoid good security practices. With something like `sudo`, every command that's executed with super-user powers is logged, along with the specific user that requested it be executed.

Comment: Good, so if we don't care about any of those we can go ahead and use root. Afterall, there is usually nothing stopping normal users from sending absolutely any network packet into your network, the only thing non root usually can't do is listen on low port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to and it is insecure.

You just don't want application to run with elevated privileges. There was a bug a while ago in an application that would erase everything on you /usr directory. If the application was running as an ordinary user that user should not have enough permission to execute that action.

You would also start your browser with elevated privileges as well. Infected web pages exploring failures in that browse could compromise your system among other problems.

There was a similar question on ubuntu forum a few years ago, you might want to check:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root